# I need help in parsing this sentence

Tags: parsing

> Cast as eavesdropper and voyeur by Iago, Othello imagines and thus constitutes a sexual encounter and pleasure that excludes him, and a Desdemona as whore instead of fair angel.

Does the sentence mean that "Othello imagines and thus constitutes"

a) a sexual counter and pleasure that excludes him AND

b) a Desdemona as whore instead of fair angel"?

But then "Othello ... constitutes a Desdemona as whore instead of fair angel" sounds awkward.

Comment: It's *very* obscure "wordy" phrasing. I confess I don't really understand the use of ***constitutes*** here. Normally it means *to establish or set up, to give being or form to something*. But in this context I can't see how Othello "creates" anything - he's just *imagining* a sexual encounter and pleasure (that Desdemona has with someone *else*, not him). So because he imagines she's having sex with someone else, that means he can think of her (imagine her, *constitute* her) as a whore rather than an angel. Awful writing though, imho.

Comment: What is the source of this sentence?

Comment: @CollenV 

From an academic article. I suspect a verb is missing before "a Desdemona."

Comment: academic writing by a non-native English speaker, I'd say. constitute is misused. Did you, by any chance, write this? It sounds like Spanish or French structure...a person does not "constitute a sexual encounter". "a Desdemona as whore" is the one thing in the sentence that is, in fact, well said.

Comment: @Lambie lol, if I wrote that sentence myself, why would I be confused about its meaning?

Comment: Regardless of who wrote it, it just ain't English.